# adb doesn't work

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

I downloaded SDK from the official website.
I installed it, but when I try to use it this happens:

[image: terminal]

What mistake did I make?

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Does it have executable permissions? What does 'ls -l' gives?

Comment: Why don't you just download adb directly ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install additional packages required for adb to work?

According to [Google Android's SDK Page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)

> If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine,
>   you need to install additional packages first. For Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy
>   Salamander) and above, install the `libncurses5:i386`,
>   `libstdc++6:i386`, and `zlib1g:i386` packages using apt-get:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
> ```
>
> For earlier versions of Ubuntu, install the `ia32-libs` package using
>   apt-get:
>
> ```
> apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```

You can check all the dependencies an executable needs using `objdump -x ./adb | grep NEEDED`.

Make sure all required packages are present in your system. And finally, as @Firelord said, also make sure that the file is executable.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250085/bash-cannot-find-adb-even-though-its-definitely-there4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972641/ubuntu-64-with-android-64-bundle-cannot-find-adb-executable) similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just install adb from Ubuntu official repository.
Run:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

In terminal for adb and

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot
```

For fastboot. In this way you can use adb and fastboot in any directory! Make sure your usb debugging is enabled.

Comment: Because he has it already.

Comment: Also, you are right, this will install necessary dependencies, in case they were the problem.

Comment: "*In this way you can use adb and fastboot in any directory!*" - that is true but if OP solves the actual problem they can make an alias for the ADB binary in SDK which would work from anywhere in the system too.